# Rules on surjective and Injective

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So I am trying to prove $f([a]+[b]) = f([a]) + f([b])$ for $\mathbb Z$ mod $12$ and the same for multiplication...  Can you show that this is true based on a function being surjection and injective and any combination of the two without showing every possibility of every element in $\mathbb Z$ mod $12$?  Is there any definitions stating this?

Comment: Where does $f$ map from/to?

Comment: Zmod 12 to Zmod4 for the function f(x)=3x

Comment: Exactly how the original exercise was worded??

Comment: it says it is mapped from Zmod12 to Zmod4 defined by f(x)=3x

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand right, you are given $f(x)=3x$, defined on $\Bbb Z_{12}$.

This maps $0\mapsto 0,\ 1\mapsto 3,\ 2\mapsto 6,\ 3\mapsto 9,\ 4\mapsto 0,\ \dots$.

We can say that $f:\Bbb Z_{12}\to\Bbb Z_{12}$, in this case it is neither injective nor surjective. (Why?)

The range of $f$ is $im(f)=\{0,3,6,9\}\subseteq\Bbb Z_{12}$ which is *isomorphic to* $\Bbb Z_4=\{0,1,2,3\}$.

So, we can also write $f:\Bbb Z_{12}\to\, im(f)\ \cong \Bbb Z_4$, and in this sense $f$ is going to be surjective.

And, finally, the fact that $f$ preserves addition follows simply by *linearity*:
$$f(a+b)\ =\ 3(a+b)\ =\ 3a\ +\ 3b\ =\ f(a)\,+\,f(b)\,.$$

Comment: so is it directly related to being surjective? is there a statement that directly correlates the two?

Comment: $f$ is not going to be injective if defined on $\Bbb Z_{12}$ as $f(0)=f(4)$.

Comment: yeah i already know this function is surjective and not injective.... i was just asked to show this question for both addition and multiplication.  I could list all the elements out in Zmod12 but I just wanted a good fact to prove this easily because it was surjective and not injective. ... I think addition holds just not multiplication

Comment: what does the notation im(f) mean?